# Does chrome extension have listener for chrome toolbar like back/forward/refresh button and address bar?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, toolbar, address-bar

I want to determine whether user used browser toolbar in chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

The closest there is is the [`webNavigation` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation).

With it you can [discern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#type-TransitionType) forward-or-back events, and reload events.

However, it won't tell you that it was specifically the toolbar that was used and not, say, a hotkey or a mouse key.